# Using Android ADT eclipse bundle on 32 bit and moving on to 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

I am starting a new android app and I am creating it on a 32 bit machine and I was wondering if it would cause any problems moving it to a 64 bit machine sometime down the line?

Can I just keep running the 32 bit version on the 64 bit machine without problems or will I have to use 64 bit eclipse? also would this affect the rest of my files?

Answer (score 1):

No real problem. Just use Eclipse for your architecture. You maybe have to install additional libs (keyword: ia32-libs). Your sources and project won't be affected from this change.

Comment: Thanks michi. All i wanted to know was whether it was going to be a big problem for me down the line at some point.